# XPath: get element type with xsd file

Tags: c#, xpath, xsd

i have a win form application in c#.
i would get all data type from my xsd using xpath.
my xsd is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"      
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:simpleType name="newdata">
<xs:union memberTypes="xs:data">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value=""/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:union>
  </xs:simpleType>  
  <xs:element name="DocumentElement">
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="UserSettings">
         <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="ID_UTENTE"  type="newdecimal" />   
             <xs:element name="PAR_DATA" type="newdata" />            
             <xs:element name="MYDATA" type="xs:date" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

so i would obtain element MYDATA AND PAR_DATA
can you help me?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `XmlDocument` as shown here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which would correspond with your XPATH desired solution or you can [deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your `xml` with [help of your `xsd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and search it in code.